# React Testing Library: fireEvent change is not working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, momentjs, react-testing-library

When I tried to change DatePicker input I am getting error.
Here is my files for components and testcase:

**datePicker.js**

```
  const DatePicker = ({ value, onChange, name, locale }) => {
      const myVal = value ? value.locale(locale) : '';
      return (
       <TextInput
         value={myVal}
         onChange={onChange}
         name={name}
       />)
  };
export default DatePicker;
```

**date.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from './datepicker';
const Date = () => { 
   const [dates, setDate] = useState('');
   return (
      <DatePicker
        name="date"
        value={dates}
        onChange={(_, value) => setDate(value)}
        locale="ja" 
      />
 ); }
```

**date.test.js**

```
test('should render Date properly', () => {
const component = render(<Date />);

const date = component.container.querySelector(
  'input[name="date"]'
);
fireEvent.change(date, {
  target: {
    value: '10/1/2021',
  },
 });
});
```

Here is the error which I am getting :

```
 TypeError: value.locale is not a function
 fireEvent.change(date, {
           ^
     target: {
        value: '10/1/2021',
     },
```

Comment: If the `value` prop is meant to be a string why do you call `value.locale(locale)` in the `DatePicker` component? That's what's causing the issue, because `value` is `'10/1/2021'` in the test, so `value.locale` does not exist.

Comment: Because on display of date I want to show date on japanese or anyother language in DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

I am personally have the issues with the change fire event however one thing I see that you have wrong is invalid formatting. React testing library specifically states that the target value for that event on a date input type has to be 00-00-000.
https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/

```
// Invalid:
fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: '24/05/2020'}})

// Valid:
fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: '2020-05-24'}})
```